# pandas python Drop last row of group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need to drop the last member of each group as it's messing up further calculations. I don't know how better to explain my problem, but if you need further clarification, please ask.

My current code:

```
 sampleDataUser = sampleData.groupby('user').filter(lambda x: x != sampleDataUser.tail(1))
```

returns this error:

```
  ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

Sample Data:

```
df = [{ "user" : "seth", var1 = "5"}, {"user": "seth", "var1" : "8"}, {"user" : "chris", "var1" : "2"}]
```

Expected output:

```
df = [{ "user" : "seth", var1 = "5"}, {"user" : "chris", "var1" : "2"}]
```

Comment: maybe you want to keep just the first row per user: `df.drop_duplicates('user', keep='first')`?

Answer (score 0):

For remove last row of `user` if is duplicated use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) chained by `|` for bitwise `OR` for mask and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{ "user" : "seth", "var1" : "50"},
                   { "user" : "seth", "var1" : "5"}, 
                   {"user": "seth", "var1" : "8"}, 
                   {"user" : "chris", "var1" : "2"}])
print (df)
    user var1
0   seth   50
1   seth    5
2   seth    8
3  chris    2

df = df[df['user'].duplicated(keep='last') | ~df['user'].duplicated(keep=False)]
print (df)
    user var1
0   seth   50
1   seth    5
3  chris    2
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.assign(m1 = df['user'].duplicated(keep='last'),
                 m2 = ~df['user'].duplicated(keep=False),
                 both = df['user'].duplicated(keep='last') | 
                       ~df['user'].duplicated(keep=False)))
    user var1     m1     m2   both
0   seth   50   True  False   True
1   seth    5   True  False   True
2   seth    8  False  False  False
3  chris    2  False   True   True
```